datagrid toolbar item state-dependent
I have a problem. I am learning to wrap datagrid and wrap children in toolbar, but the button display does not change with the state, the props parameter is changed, why?enter image description hereenter image description here
The childrenList is the button component, and disable in props changes normally. But the display didn't change
//selectRows state Should affect Item Whether disabled
 <Toolbar visible={true}>
    {childrenList.map((items: any, index: number) => {
        const itemRender: any = (item: any) => {
          childrenRefs.current[items?.props?.name] = createRef();
          return items
            ? React.cloneElement(items, { ref: childrenRefs.current[items.props?.name] })
            : null;
        };
        return (
          <Item
            key={'zdy' + index}
            location="before"
            locateInMenu="auto"
            // visible={isPermission(items?.props?.name)} 
            menuItemRender={itemRender}
            render={itemRender}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Toolbar>

   <Button type="primary" onClick={add} disabled={selectRows?.selectedRowsData?.length != 1}>
          Input Button Name
  </Button>


